# sqlite pair columns that reference similar values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table my_table

```
sport            score
football         22
basketball       17
baseball         17
baseball         29
hockey           22
```

I want to pair columns in sport that have the same score

the desired output should be

```
sport1      sport2        times_paired
football    hockey        1
basketball  baseball      1
```

so far in my query i have

```
select m1.sport as sport1, m1.score as times_paired, m2.sport as sport2 from mytable m1 where(select count(*) as times_paired, m2.sport  from mytable2 m2 where m1.score = m2.score.
```

This query above does not work. How can i achieve the desired results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An inner self join and an aggregation might be what you're looking for.

```
SELECT t1.sport sport1,
       t2.sport sport2,
       count(*) times_paired
       FROM my_table t1
            INNER JOIN my_table t2
                       ON t2.score = t1.score
                          AND t2.sport > t1.sport
       GROUP BY t1.sport,
                t2.sport;
```